# I need to use this command "systemctl --user restart pulseaudio" every time I boot for audio to work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I need to use this command "systemctl --user restart pulseaudio" every time i boot for audio to work. Without this command my audio is not working. Kindly Help..

Comment: Do you have an encrypted home? if so ... pulse needs to be started after it is mounted not before. What does `systemctl status pulseaudio` state? (edit the question so the comments can be removed as we progress)

Answer (score 2):

Run :

```
echo 'systemctl --user restart pulseaudio' >> /home/$USER/pulse.sh
chmod +x /home/$USER/pulse.sh
```

Then go to the startup application and add a new entry.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN3VO.png]

Inside the command field type:

```
gnome-terminal -- /home/your_user_name/pulse.sh
```

Now when the system will start the command will be executed automatically.

Comment: I agree with this as a temp. fix :-)

Comment: yup,, Thanks a Lot. Work's Fine now.